# Downloading files from password protected urls using wget

Tags: linux, wget

I am downloading many files from a password-protected server. They suggested using:
wget -i urllist.txt --user name --ask-password
to download files. I am able to download files but the problem is I want to change all files with each step of running this script so that I will have the correct files name.
For a single file download -output option was working but for many files, I am having a problem. Can you help me out?

Comment: Not a programming question, and as such off-topic here.  Voted to close.  Maybe try [unix.se] or [su]?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your information. As I am new here, I don't know many things about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean with:

> I want to change all files with each step of running this script so
>   that I will have the correct files name.

How about if you download all files to a folder and later rename they way you want?

`wget` manuals says:

> -P prefix
>   --directory-prefix=prefix Set directory prefix to prefix.  The directory prefix is the directory where all other files and
>   subdirectories will be saved to, i.e. the top of the retrieval tree. 
>   The default is . (the current directory).

Therefore you could use:

```
wget -P download-folder -i urllist.txt --user name --ask-password
```

Now you call manually rename the files in `download-folder`.

Comment: Hi, Rafa thank you so much for your help. Yes, I am able to download images, but what I mean is: as we use, ''wget -O some_name url" to get the name of the downloaded file. Similarly, is there any method so that each file download has their specific name I provide. Because there will be a problem in assigning a name to each URL by there specific name after download. So I want to change the name simultaneously with it considering the above password protected URL.

Comment: In this case, a script is probably the best option. Something simple with a loop iterating each item in your `urllist.txt` and a rule for renaming the files by the conditions you want.

Comment: Yes finally did it using script in python. Thanks for your help https://stackoverflow.com/users/1943878/rafa